# MySQL Connector 6.6.4 with mod_mono and mono

Tags: mysql, mono

Which is PublicTokenKey and additionally what I need to write in web.config.
I mean MySql.Data.Dll that has version 6.6.4 (I downloaded latest from official website)
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the PublicTokenKey -> c5687fc88969c44d

If you use linux you can find this info from this path:
/usr/lib/mono/gac/MySql.Data/6.6.4.0__c5687fc88969c44d
For windows see this link:
https://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly.aspx?Redirected=true